# Where is the default directory of the export csv file that COPY generated in cassandra?

Tags: docker, cassandra, cqlsh

I'm using `COPY` command of `Cassandra` to export data to a `csv` file.

```
cqlsh > COPY music.songs to 'songs.csv';
```

I don't know where to find the the exported `csv` file.

I'm using `Cassandra` in `Docker` running on `Wins7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find -name "songs.csv"` to find out that the `csv` file was exported to the directory where I ran `cqlsh` command.

Comment: Can we get the location of the file? I have exported the file but while importing its saying cannot open the file.

Comment: Do you mean you couldn't find out where the generated file was?

Comment: If you run `cqlsh` command at a location such as `/home/username`, then you find the file just at this location.

Comment: Thank you got it. niaomingjian